# Multiple script links in index.html

Tags: html, angularjs, gulp

I've got a little project in Angular. I'm trying to keep everything in the Single Responsibility way and
I'm quite happy with me app structure. The only think I feel is not looking very good is index.html. All js files are included on
the bottom of the file and I do not like the look of it. I'm adding more files (controllers, services, etc) as I go and the list
could grow quite long.

So my question is: Is it normal,that the index file includes all these or is there way to move all these in a single file and reference that in the index.html?

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...

    ...


<script src="assets/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/controllerOne.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/controllerTwo.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/controllerThree.js"></script>
<script src="directives/directiveOne.js"></script>
<script src="directives/directiveTwo.js"></script>
<script src="services/serviceOne.js"></script>
<script src="services/serviceTwo.js"></script>
<script src="services/serviceThree.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update 07/04/2015**

I have end up using Gulp. For anyone looking for bit of help on this, I have followed this small tutorial: https://medium.com/@dickeyxxx/best-practices-for-building-angular-js-apps-266c1a4a6917

Comment: vidriduch, did my answer solved your issue?

Comment: I'll use it as a hint... I will leave the question open for a while. I would like to research Grunt,Gulp and require.js bit more, give them a try and I will update this acordingly.

Comment: Sure, You are welcomed to post your conclusions after your research. good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few possible solutions that I know that will automatically inject your script tags for index.html:

1. Using [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) - Task / Build runner.
   You can use [Gulp-Inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) which is:

   > a stylesheet, javascript and webcomponent reference injection plugin
   >   for gulp
2. [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) - JavaScript Task Runner
   You can use [Grunt-Injector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-injector) for:

   > Inject references to files into other files (think scripts and stylesheets into an html file)
3. Another option which I didn't use is [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).
   See - http://www.startersquad.com/blog/angularjs-requirejs/

You can find many discussions on Gulp vs Grunt, Both will make your life easier and solve your problem.

See:

[Grunt vs Gulp](http://jaysoo.ca/2014/01/27/gruntjs-vs-gulpjs/)

[Another Grunt vs Gulp](https://medium.com/@preslavrachev/gulp-vs-grunt-why-one-why-the-other-f5d3b398edc4)

Answer (score 2):

What i would suggest is using a task runner of some sort to concatenate all your files, and build them in to something like a single 'app.js' file.

My personal preference is gulp, but another popular alternative is grunt. [Here](https://medium.com/@dickeyxxx/best-practices-for-building-angular-js-apps-266c1a4a6917) is a nice introduction to using gulp with angular which I suggest checking out.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is utterly normal for a development stage as it facilitates debugging. You shouldn't be worried about the way it looks.

However, when releasing your application to production you should concatenate all scripts into one single file as this'll significantly boost your bootstrap time. There are different ways of achieving this goal and usually they involve usage of front-side build tools like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). It's is up to you to decide which tool will work best for you.

Moreover, [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) has built-in modularity with a easy-to-use tool for concatenation, though, it's argued that Angular benefits from using it as Angular has it's own modularity. The main advantage of require.js is that there's no need to pay attention to order in which your files are concatenated since it's responsibility of the tool. Unfortunately, it costs a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

Using **require.js** , u can manage all tags in one line

Answer (score 1):

As a simple solution, in HTML5 you can do this

```
<link rel="import" href="header.html">
```

and place all your

```
<script src="libs/....js"></script>
<script src="libs/....js"></script>
<script src="libs/....js"></script>
```

in the header.html

Comment: What if browser does n't support html5?

Comment: "HTML Imports is deprecated and will be removed in M73, around March 2019. Please use ES modules instead"

Answer (score 0):

It's ok. Separating different scripts into different files is a part of basic recommandations for code styling.

The best way is to use Google Style recommendations in work. These 2 are for html&css and javascript:

https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml

https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml